# USB-C Monitor with DVI Out Graphics Card

Tags: graphics-card, display, dvi, usb-c

Ok gents... should be an easy question for someone who has had experience here before.

I am wanting to order a stand-alone monitor that only has USB-C in. My desktop computer however uses a graphics card that only has HDMI/Display Port/DVI out. Can this be easily adapted or no? It is important to note that the USB-C in on the monitor also provides power.

Thanks.

Comment: [USB-C is a mess](https://superuser.com/a/1200112/41259) care to elaborate which monitor? The 27MD5K is a Thunderbolt 3 monitor for example and it would violate the TB3 standard not to have any PCI Express or USB 3 signals on the cable and you can't conjure those out of thin air -- just a video signal in is not enough. If you have a monitor which uses DP alt mode USB C then it is at least possible but noone made it and unlikely it'll ever be made, alas so I mark this as a duplicate of the other question affirming a negative.

Answer (score 0):

*It depends*. There's purely USB 3.0 based monitors with an internal video card. Most of these are made by display link and if it provides power, its likely one of these. You would need some flavour of USB C connector, and your internal video card connections would not matter.

As of 2016/2017 though, there's monitors that use USB 3.0 in displayport alternate mode, or thunderbolt. These often also *charge laptops* that use these port to charge, acting almost like a dock.

So, do your homework, and look up some reviews. *Typically* you should find this information in your manual.